# Excel VBA - GetObject(), Open read-only (already open docs)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use excel VBA to open another excel document to pull data.
I would like to be able to open and pull data from documents that are already open by other users.
How can I get GetObject function to open the file with read-only parameters?

Comment: Check the **[Workbooks.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx)** method.  There is a _ReadOnly_ parameter.

Comment: So.. is there no "read-only" parameter for the GetObject method?

Comment: Not even sure that **[GetObject Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445016(v=vs.60).aspx)** applies in this case but it certainly has no _Read-Only_ flag.

Comment: i currently use GetObject() to do what I need (without the read-only portion), but thank you

Comment: Anyhow, I still think `Workbook.Open` more suited for this kind of use.  But what is good about `GetObject` is that it seems to open the workbook as "Hidden", it is good to know :)

Comment: hmm... hidden as in, it doesn't show up at all? so then does GetObject() still require Application.ScreenUpdating and the like?

Comment: In fact, it opens the workbook with all the worksheets hidden.  You still have access to them programmatically though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Workbooks.Open` method and specify the full path name with ReadOnly set to true:

```
    Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\excelworkbook.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
```

Assuming that workbook is already open, it will open as read-only. Select all the cells from this read-only workbook, copy, and paste everything into your other workbook.

**Here is the code:**

```
    'Hide Prompts and Screen Updating (so can rename workbooks without prompts)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Create Two WorkBook Objects
        Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook

        'Create a new workbook to copy to
        Set Wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Add()
        Wb1.SaveAs ("WorkBookToCopyTo")

        'Open the other workbook (will open as read-only because it's already open)
        Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\excelworkbook.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)

        'activate read-only workbook, select all cells, copy
        Wb2.Activate
        Wb2.Worksheets(1).Select

        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'activate other workbook, select all cells, paste
        Wb1.Activate
        Wb1.Worksheets(1).Select

        Cells.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Show Prompts Again
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can activate read only workbooks with the following code:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file-path, ReadOnly:=True
```